# List View / Details View without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

I have a MVC [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jINUv.png) that has a table that contains a list of all users within a specific OU within Active Directory. I am trying to add a column to the table that takes you to a Details view that shows the details of the user (shows additional details) but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this without using Entity Framework and passing the id of the object to the details view. Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this? Right now when I click on the Details actionlink, I am taken to the Details view but there is no data being passed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public ActionResult NonComputerUsers(User model)
    {  
      
        List<User> user = new List<User>();
       
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "XXX", "OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=com"))
        {
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    user.Add(new User()
                    {
                        FirstName = (String)entry.Properties["givenName"].Value,
                        LastName = (String)entry.Properties["sn"].Value,
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return View(user.ToList());
    }


 public ActionResult Details(User model)
    {
        ?????????
        

        return View(model);
    }



**List View**
@model ADUserManagement.Models.User

<table class="table">
 <tr>
    <th>
        First Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Last Name
    </th>

 </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        
        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Users", new { item = item.FirstName })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

```
**Details View**
@model ADUserManagement.Models.User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>@Model.FirstName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>@Model.LastName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SAM Account Name</td>
    <td>@Model.SamAccountName</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Remove the `User model` parameter in both methods. Your `Details` method needs an `int id` parameter and the 'Details' link will pass the ID of the User to that method

Comment: Since the user info is coming from Active Directory, there is no ID set for a user, and if I remove User model from both methods then I am unable to pass any user info from the List view to the Details view, I just get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Thank you for your input though!

Comment: Active Directory user do have unique ID's - e.g. ,`sAMAccountName` etc

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. One of which is the way you are already doing it. You can add all the properties you want to display on your details page to your `User` model. Use that list to build your table, then pass the applicable `User` object back to your `Details` view to display the extra details.

That method is good because it saves you having to do a second lookup to AD for your `Details` view (essentially, your `?????????` can be removed - you don't need any code there).

I was going to say that the down side is that, in your search, you're asking for more details for most of the accounts than you'd actually use, but the `UserPrincipal` objects that `PrincipalSearcher` returns already pulls in all the AD attributes for each user account anyway. If you used `DirectorySearcher` directly, you'd have more control of that. But that's probably not a big deal, unless you have performance problems with that search.

The other way to do it, which I think is unnecessary in your current example, is to store some unique identifier from AD (e.g. `distinguishedName`, `sAMAccountName`, `userPrincipalName`, `objectGuid`, `objectSid`) and pass just that back to your `Details` action where you can look up just that account again and get all the details you need for your Details view.